# Best practices for re-fech an item in a list react-query

Tags: react-query

How do you guys handle the case:

- Query return list of post
- Then edit the post, so I just need to fetch detail of that post again

It might somehow be related to normalization but I think we can have some best-practice to handle this.

Maybe we can have a keys

- List: `['post']`
- Post item: `['post', {id: number}]`

Then when we fetch the list, we actually set data for the post items, and the `['list']` only save the id.

Does that make sense? or anyone have a better solution for this

Answer (score 5):

You can either prefetch your posts using [`QueryClient.prefetchQuery`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/prefetching) and then display them by retrieving individual posts from cache by id or you can perform optimistic update using single query key like this:

```tsx
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

const { mutate } = useMutation(someUpdateFn, {
  onMutate: async (post) => {
    await queryClient.cancelQueries(["posts"]);

    queryClient.setQueryData(["posts"], (posts) => {
      const previousPosts = posts.filter(({ id }) => post.id !== id);

      return [...previousPosts, post];
    });
  },
});
```

You can read more about optimistic updates [here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/optimistic-updates)

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, but my case is more complex because the list of posts is fetched as infinity query so changing its state seems difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

At a certain point, you should just manage your own state, global or local, via your own array and such. Do fetches with axios and add, delete, modify your own cache.

I have tried some complicated stuff and sooner or later, doing react query and making it work isn't worth it in my opinion. However, for most cases, react query is just brilliant.